# Numbering in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

```
# Header 

## Header 

### Header 

[my favorite site](https://www.vseborec.cz/index.php?xx=3)

*Text*

**Text**
```

My question is how to number the content in rmarkdown from for this line of code in r-markdown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `number_sections: true` option.

```
---
title: "Numbered"
author: "Abdur Rohman"
date: '2022-05-07'
output: 
 html_document:
   number_sections: true
---


# Header 

## Header 

### Header 

[my favorite site](https://www.vseborec.cz/index.php?xx=3)

*Text*

**Text**
```

The html output:

[image]

In case you want to number the lines other than headers, you just type the numbers on the beginning of each line:

```
1. [my favorite site](https://www.vseborec.cz/index.php?xx=3)
2. *Text*
3. **Text**
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: i know. but my task is to number ALL of these lines from 1 to 7

Comment: Could you show how the expected output looks like? I mean, what are the numbers for the link and for the *Text*?

Comment: just every line of code should be numbered

Comment: Please check my edited answer